# Folklore Lemma (p-adic case)

Tags: diophantine-approximation

Is there a p-adic version of the so called 'folklore lemma' which relates a sequence of diophnatine approximations to an algebraic number to the exponential of irrationality.

Comment: Dear Kale, this is too vague.  What is the "exponential of irrationality" ?  Many of your other questions have gone unanswered because it is not clear what you are asking.  Unless you explain a bit more (for example what the "folklore lemma" is), and ask precise questions, you are unlikely to get any answers, and your questions are liable to be closed.  I've voted to close this one.

Comment: What Chandan said. In particular, maybe you could state the non-$p$-adic version of the folklore lemma, so we'd all know what we're looking for. 

Comment: I'm almost sure it refers to something like lemma 1 in  http://algo.inria.fr/seminars/sem01-02/brisebarre.ps